# how to make the python program light, which is written to print the text on screen directly without window?

Tags: python-3.x, text, tkinter, screen, light

From last few days, I have been working on a program which one part is to show the text directly on the window screen, and also update/change them as per requirement. I have completed this part with Tkinter module in python.

The problem is whenever I run the program it behaves like a heavy program due to which other processes become slow. Also If I tried to do some other process in parallel, the background of the text becomes black, which is absolutely undesirable.[as the shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE2Ol.jpg)

I also want to show some dynamic symbol like loading but the use of two Tkinter widget make it slower. if possible please make it more modular and light.

```
from tkinter import *
import win32api, win32con, pywintypes
from time import sleep

f=Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set(' ')
f =Label(textvariable = var, font=('Cooper','60'), fg='blue', bg='white')
f.master.overrideredirect(True)
f.master.geometry("+900+200")
f.master.lift()
f.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
f.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
f.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
f.pack()


for i in range(10):
    sleep(5) # Need this to slow the changes down
    var.set(u'[ A ]' if i%2 else u'[ B ]')
    f.update_idletasks()
```

also, want to ask can we do it without using the Tkinter module.so it becomes more light and modular. and dependency will be less.

Comment: You are calling delay. So its slowing down.

Comment: I am not talking about the more time of execution. My concern is whenever I run the program it is not working properly. It feels like it is slowing down the system process. I know how delay function works. @BlackThunder

Comment: Is it not responding?

Comment: I have added an image...please see that...yeah it seems like it will go unresponsive any movement. sorry, I am not good with technical explanation. I hope You can understand the problem... @BlackThunder

Comment: sorry...It is working on my system but whenever I go for any other process even right click...it goes unresponsive...and this is the main problem I want to resolve.

Comment: Are you talking about white borders of text or making it responsive?

Comment: can you suggest the another approch?

Comment: If you want to make it responsive then I can answer you.

Comment: I want to make it responsive and light weighted so...so it can be more flexible to use throughout another program. As this is the only a part of another program.

Comment: What do you mean by light weighted?

Comment: I mean to say...It'll not take too much ram and run smoothly with other program also...

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly slow down the system. It spends about 99% of it's time sleeping, which means it uses virtually no CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which makes your code responsive and also don't use your cpu too much.

```
from tkinter import *
import win32api, win32con, pywintypes
import time

f=Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set(' ')
f =Label(textvariable = var, font=('Cooper','60'), fg='blue', bg='white',bd=0)
f.master.overrideredirect(True)
f.master.geometry("+900+200")
f.master.lift()
f.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
f.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
f.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
f.pack()


for i in range(10):
    f.update()
    t = time.time()
    while time.time() - t < 5:
        f.update()
    var.set(u'[ A ]' if i%2 else u'[ B ]')
    f.update_idletasks()
    f.update()
```

Here is an image of task manager. Its taking only `15 MB` memory and no cpu:

[image]

Comment: can you explain why while `time.time() - t < 5: f.update()` works

Comment: `time.time()` gives the current time in second and minus `t` (it is not updated, it is the time captured before the while loop) from that. If the output is more than five then it stops. `f.update()` updates the interface.